# Why were my 'not an answer' flags declined?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, declined-flags

I flagged an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911241/how-to-set-chmod-777-in-image-upload/26830420#26830420) as 'not an answer', because it should actually be a comment (it asks a question, and doesn't answer the question):

[image]

However:

[image]

The flag was declined as `flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer`. The question does ***not*** have any technical inaccuracies or is not a wrong answer; ***it just doesn't answer the question***.

As this was a result of this answer coming up in my review queue, I'd like to know *why* my flag was declined since in my opinion my flag was justified.

***Edit:***
I flagged yet another answer on the very same question that clearly ***did not*** answer the question:

[image]

oh, and guess what, ***it was declined!***

[image]

Comment: I second your opinion. That answer should be a comment.

Comment: How does "just set those permissions on the folder you are uploading to" not answer the question? It's a pretty crappy answer and pretty much repeats the information you could already get from the answer above it, but it is still an answer.

Comment: @animuson The original question asks in relation to the *code*, and *not* 'will chmod 666 solve the problem?' or any variant of this.

Comment: @cybermonkey I think you're reading too much into it. If everyone only ever directly answered the question without ever providing alternatives **that still answer the question** then this place would be a disaster zone. We're clearly dealing with a new user who doesn't understand how permissions work. And checking *every single time* to see if your permissions are correct is a pretty silly thing to do. Changing it on your file system is the *best* answer IMO.

Comment: Another flag was declined on the same question: http://puu.sh/cJRo1/33a99172b2.png. ***The second flag clearly is justified, but still was declined.***

Comment: @animuson Apparently the wider community disagree with you on that one: http://puu.sh/cKJt6/1e7d50012f.png. That answer's probably going to be deleted by Community automatically in the next day or so (how it usually works). Also because my question (currently) stands at +4/-3.

Comment: I put this together when  I was a mod on SF it may help you. http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5316/when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: @Iain Extract from the answer you gave: ***The answer is asking for additional information or making a comment on the question - we can convert to a comment.***. If we go by this, ***both*** these 'answers' should be comments and both my flags should have been accepted instead of declined. *I even flagged one of them as VLQ, but still got declined as `don't re-flag a question just to get it deleted if your first flag was declined`.

Comment: @cybermonkey Then the correct thing to do is help the mods by providing a link to where it should be a comment which is also noted in my answer :) Also note that mods have guidance but act (broadly) independently, one mod may accept the NAA and another may not, it's best to provide as much information to help them get the job done as possible.

Comment: @Iain I *did* do that, however the comments were removed by a moderator (I suspect it was animuson) when my flags were declined. I feel like I'm fighting a losing battle here; if I re-flag the moderators are going to see that there have already been a couple of declined flags on those 'answers' by me, and they're just going to decline the flag yet again.

Comment: @Iain Thing is, I *want* to flag ***both*** those 'answers' for full moderator attention, but however am afraid they're going to be declined and I'll get a flag-ban. As I'm already under a pretty-deep question ban (I've had it since 470 reputation, I believe it's a bug in the Stack Exchange platform..), I'm afraid my account will be suspended.

Comment: @cybermonkey you did flag them for _full moderator attention_ an NAA flag does that. The NAA flag is a very blunt instrument - you are basically saying this does not attempt to answer the question. I would argue that both the answers you flagged are an attempt to provide a solution to the problem and are therefore answers so your NAA flags were correctly declined. You should have just DV (if you are inclined to do so) and moved on.

Comment: @Iain I had also flagged both those 'answers' as VLQ (because they are low quality), those flags also were declined.

Comment: VLQ is not the subject of this question. The answers are correctly punctuated and understandable, they attempt to answer the question - what's VLQ about that ?

Comment: Here's the part where I pose a hypothetical question?  Here's the part where I suggest a low-quality answer to the problem.  Here's the part where you vote NAA, and here's the part where the mod decides to not delete it because it kinda sorta is an answer and the community can handle it on their own.  Here's the part where I point this out to you, and here's the point where you angrily reply and tell me the same thing you've said over and over, apparently not taking in the point of my comment.

Comment: @Will You never commented here on this question, so how can I 'take the point in of your comment'?

Comment: Here's the part where I [link to my comment on your question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276406/why-were-my-not-an-answer-flags-declined?noredirect=1#comment115899_276406), and here's the part where you still don't get it.

Comment: @Will I (and everyone else) cannot read minds, the point about your comment is invalid as you implied you had a previous comment

Comment: And here's the part where I stop trying, and here's the part where you go off thinking I'm the one who's the problem.

Comment: @Will I do not understand what you're trying to imply here. ***Multiple users here have agreed with me that the 'answer' in fact isn't an answer, both in the comments and via upvotes on this question (currently at +4/-4). The upvotes also suggest that there exist very different opinions on what a NAA and VLQ answer is.*** Yes, there's a 50:50 split and arguing the same point over and over again (as you have done) won't change that.

Comment: One last try--they are answers, although poor. We agree on this, I think. They start with a question, but offer a solution, wrong or not. Mods have decided that they are answer enough, and are leaving it up to the community to handle them like we handle all low quality stuff. That's their prerogative, and is sometimes better than being overly heavy-handed.  And that's why this happens sometimes. The fact that the community rejects these answers doesn't mean mods should act unilaterally on them.  Simple as that.

Comment: @Will Gotcha, *although* it would have been even better if the moderators who declined my flags commented/answered here to say *why* they declined them- I just want to be a better reviewer; giving me more information would make the review decision process that *little* bit easier.

Comment: Well, from what I hear, they have a backlog of roughly a thousand flags to deal with.  Volunteers don't have too much time to spend working on them, so giving better details isn't always high on the priority.  More often than not, if a mod doesn't act, it's because they think it is better handled by the community.

Comment: @Will It's closer to 12k if we account for *every* flag.